# Console based file fetcher from URL with embedded file downloader

Tags: python, beginner

I'm new to programming. I wrote this following console based app in Python. It's a simple python script to fetch size, type and extension of a file from a given URL. it also includes an embedded downloader. To access that user has to input certain credentials in the console window. I'd like someone to suggest something to make this code more efficient and shorter.

```
r""" GetFileInfoURLV2.py: A simple python script to fetch size, type and extension of a file from a given URL. it also includes an embedded downloader. To access that user has to input certain credentials in the console window. """

__author__ = 'AJ'
__version__ = '2.0.0'


import os
import sys

import requests as r
import uuid


URL = ''  # to hold given URL in the memory


def file_size_converter(size):
    """ A function to convert 'bytes' into human understandable e.g. MB or KB """

    magic = lambda x: str(round(size / round(x / 1024), 2))  # an algorithm that returns bytes into smaller size

    size_in_int = [int(1 << 10), int(1 << 20), int(1 << 30), int(1 << 40), int(1 << 50), int(1 << 60), int(1 << 70),
               int(1 << 80), int(1 << 90)]  # size in integer format e.g. int(i << 30) == 1099511627776
    size_in_text = ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB', 'PB', 'EB', 'ZB', 'YB']  # human readable file-size(HRS) format
    for i in size_in_int:
        if size < i:
            g = size_in_int.index(i)
            position = int((1024 % i) / 1024 * g)  # this returns index value for size_in_text list to determine HRS
            ss = magic(i)
            return ss + ' ' + size_in_text[position]


def downloader(url):
    """ A function to download file in the HDD from a URL """

    try:
        file_name = url.rsplit('/', 1)[-1].replace('/', '').replace('*', '').replace('"', '').replace('\\', '').replace(
        '?', '').replace('<', '').replace('>', '').replace(':', '').replace('|', '')  # removes unnecessary markers
    except IndexError:
        file_name = str(uuid.uuid4() + url[-4:])  # to give random filename
    file_path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser('~'), 'Desktop', file_name)
    raw_data = r.get(url, stream=True)
    try:
        if os.path.exists(file_path):
            print(str(file_path) + ' already exists!!!')
            pass
        else:
            with open(file_path, 'wb') as f:
                for chunk in raw_data.iter_content(chunk_size=2048):
                    if chunk:
                        f.write(chunk)
            print(url + ' has been downloaded')
    except Exception:
        print(url + ' couldn\'t be downloaded')
        pass


def get_file_info_from_url(file_url):
    """ Main algorithm to process info from the file's URL """

    infos = ['Content-Length', 'content-length', 'Content-length', 'Content-Type', 'Content-type' 'content-type']
    req = r.head(file_url)
    status_code = str(req.status_code)
    if status_code == '200':
        info_collection = [req.headers[i] for i in req.headers if i in infos]
        try:
            file_type, file_size_str = info_collection
            file_size = int(file_size_str)
        except ValueError:
            info_collection.reverse()
            try:
                file_type, file_size_str = info_collection
                file_size = int(file_size_str)
            except ValueError:
                print('Cannot retrieve info from %s, try again later' % file_url)  # cannot fetch information
                return repeat()
        try:
            file_true_type, file_extension = file_type.split('/')
        except IndexError:
            file_true_type, file_extension = file_type
        file_size_readable = file_size_converter(file_size)

        return file_true_type, file_extension, file_size_readable


def get_url():
    """ Function that returns URL input """

    while True:
        x = input('Enter the url of the file you wish to get analyzed\n>>> ')
        global URL
        URL += x
        return str(x)


def try_():
    """ Part of repeat() function that returns integer value """

    while True:
        x = input('Press 1 to search again\n'
              'Press 2 to quit').lower()
        if x in {'1', '2'}:
            clear_global_url()
            return int(x)
        if x == 'god mode':  # pass-code to access god_mode() function
            god_mode()
            repeat()
        print('Either press 1 or 2')


def god_mode():
    """ A secret function that enables downloading of file """

    c = 3  # count for limiting login attempts
    global URL
    x_url = URL
    clear_global_url()
    for i in range(1, 4):
        while i <= c:
            god_input_pass = input('>>> ')
            if god_input_pass == 'aj':  # password to download file (can be improved using hashing and etc.)
                try:
                    downloader(x_url)
                    return
                except Exception:
                    repeat()
            c -= 1
    repeat()


def clear_global_url():
    """ It deletes URL variable from memory and creates a new global URL variable """

    global URL
    del URL
    globals()['URL'] = ''


def repeat():
    """ A function to repeat the process of searching over again and quit from the app """

    _try = try_()
    if _try == 1:
        print_file_info()
    else:
        sys.exit(0)


def print_file_info():
    """ A function that prints collected info in a desired manner """

    url = get_url()
    try:
        file_true, file_ext, file_size_read = get_file_info_from_url(url)
    except TypeError:
        print('URL probably redirects, try different URL\n')
        print_file_info()
    else:
        print('''
URL %s contains the following information:
File Size: %s
File True Type: %s
File Extension: %s
''' % (url, file_size_read, file_true.capitalize(), file_ext.capitalize()))


def core():
    """ Main function A.K.A main() function """

    print('Welcome to FileInformer v 2.0 by AJ\n')
    print_file_info()  # initial search
    while True:
        repeat()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    core()
```

Comment: You call the function for turning bytes into different scales `magic` but you should always try and make your code readable so maybe call it `convert` or `convert_bytes` or something similar